# Format of bytes in Golang

Tags: python, go, encryption

I have faced up with difficulties to decode signature in bytes.
Condition:

```
 signedStringForIntermediateSigningKeySignature =
length_of_sender_id || sender_id || length_of_protocol_version || protocol_version || length_of_signed_key || signed_key
```

The "||" notation means concatenate. Each component—sender_id, protocolVersion, signedKey—must be UTF-8 encoded. The signedKey must be the string of intermediateSigningKey.signedKey. The byte length of each component is 4 bytes in little-endian format.

input:

```
signedStringForIntermediateSigningKeySignature =
\x06\x00\x00\x00 || Google || | \x04\x00\x00\x00 || ECv2 || \xb5\x00\x00\x00 || {"keyExpiration":"1542323393147","keyValue":"MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE/1+3HBVSbdv+j7NaArdgMyoSAM43yRydzqdg1TxodSzA96Dj4Mc1EiKroxxunavVIvdxGnJeFViTzFvzFRxyCw\u003d\u003d"}
```

Python version:

```
signed = b""
for a in args:
    signed += len(a).to_bytes(4, byteorder="little")
    signed += bytes(a, "utf-8")
return signed
```

output:

```
b'\x06\x00\x00\x00Google\x04\x00\x00\x00ECv2\xb5\x00\x00\x00{"keyExpiration":"1542323393147","keyValue":"MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE/1+3HBVSbdv+j7NaArdgMyoSAM43yRydzqdg1TxodSzA96Dj4Mc1EiKroxxunavVIvdxGnJeFViTzFvzFRxyCw\\u003d\\u003d"}'
```

Golang version:

```
var signed []byte
arguments := []string{SenderId, RecipientId, pv, sk}
for _, a := range arguments {
    b := make([]byte, 4)
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(b, uint32(len(a)))
    signed = append(signed, b...)
    signed = append(signed, []byte(a)...)
}
return signed
```

output:

```
[6 0 0 0 71 111 111 103 108 101 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 69 67 118 50 181 0 0 0 123 34 107 101 121 86 97 108 117 101 34 58 34 77 70 107 119 69 119 89 72 75 111 90 73 122 106 48 67 65 81 89 73 75 111 90 73 122 106 48 68 65 81 99 68 81 103 65 69 113 121 86 105 110 120 85 122 104 82 103 101 71 88 83 118 78 85 56 55 84 52 120 72 65 72 102 70 98 84 101 98 82 103 71 74 106 78 116 117 105 115 79 81 81 121 49 73 81 122 118 117 83 50 86 52 110 102 70 102 117 109 71 78 71 117 53 55 43 112 57 70 47 72 87 115 65 119 48 80 100 43 55 73 67 65 92 117 48 48 51 100 92 117 48 48 51 100 34 44 34 107 101 121 69 120 112 105 114 97 116 105 111 110 34 58 34 49 54 51 57 49 48 54 55 50 54 57 48 48 34 125]
```

I see that output is different.
Can you hint me is there any problem?

Comment: Updated: added input and output examples

Comment: The Go output in the question is not the result of running the code on the input: https://go.dev/play/p/0gU1tdcQY2S

Comment: That is my fault, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem is the viewing of output and both outputs are equal in bytes.
if you want to view your `signed` variable like Python, following code is useful:

```
signedStr := strconv.Quote(string(signed))
fmt.Println(signedStr)
```